# double backslash in string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following `NSString`s:

```
"Test Folder\t4019-130603151520.png",
"Test Folder\\Test sub\tNOICON"
```

I'm trying to differentiate between them based on the double backslash with this bit of code but it's not picking it up:

```
if (![icon rangeOfString:@"\\"].location == NSNotFound)  
{
        NSLog(@"folder %@ contains \\", icon);
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for double backslash use:

```
@"\\\\"
```

Using `@"\\"` will only look for one, because the backslash itself is the escape character,so you need to espace it.

Comment: You might also want to consider Objective-C++ with C++11 raw string literals. They don't require the extra backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is an escape character, so you need four of them: One to escape the each of the two backslashes you want to match.